# How can I find journals in my field that do not charge author fees?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, fees

I am in search of an algorithms journal that does not ask for publication fee.
It doesn't matter to me whether it is an open-access journal or not.
I have been searching for journals with no publication charges journal for a while, but have been unable to find any such journals.

Are there any resources that can help me locate journals that do not charge authors publication fees?

Comment: Could you specify if your algorithm paper is applied to a particular discipline e.g. molecular biology  or is it pure theory / a mathematically-focused algorithm paper?

Comment: What do you mean? Most journals (algorithms included) have no publication fee if your article will only be available through subscription. E.g., look on ACM, Springer journals and you will find many.

Comment: @Alexandros not such a silly question IMO. Many subscription access journals still levy 'page charges' to authors, particularly for long papers e.g. IEEE fees http://www.ieee.org/advertisement/2012vpcopc.pdf

Comment: @rmounce I never used the term silly. I do not know about IEEE but ACM and Springer journal I know of are free.

Comment: @Alexandros this 2013 survey seems to indicate that 55% of Springer journals levy 'colour' charges for colour figures: http://www.researchinfonet.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Wellcome-survey-of-colour-and-page-charges-v-02.pdf ACM not included in that survey

Comment: @DUDE_MXP: I have substantially edited the title and content of the question, because in its original form, it is asking for a list of journals, which is considered an off-topic "shopping" question. Asking for how to find no-fee journals in general, however, would be on topic.

Comment: Can you please specify field more precisely?  Most computer science journals do not charge fees, so I am guessing you mean some other field?

Comment: My algorithm is a bit graph theory based.To be precise its based on maze generation algorithm.

Comment: I don't know what subject maze generation falls under, but most graph theory journals I know do not charge author fees.

Comment: **Legitimate algorithms journals do not charge publication fees.** Those IEEE page charges are _voluntary_, which in this context is a synonym for _fictional_. (Some legit journals do charge fees for open access, but that's not the same thing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use websites like [DOAJ.org](https://doaj.org/) to search for relevant open access journals that do not charge publication fees.

This [example query for 'algorithms'](https://doaj.org/search?source=%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22filtered%22%3A%7B%22filter%22%3A%7B%22bool%22%3A%7B%22must%22%3A%5B%7B%22term%22%3A%7B%22_type%22%3A%22journal%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22term%22%3A%7B%22index.has_apc.exact%22%3A%22No%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22query_string%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%22algorithms%22%2C%22default_operator%22%3A%22OR%22%7D%7D%7D%7D%2C%22from%22%3A0%2C%22size%22%3A50%7D) reveals 40 such cost-free open access journals, some of which may be relevant to you, depending on what exact type of algorithm you're publishing.

Using this I found [*The Electronic Journal of Combinatorics*](http://www.combinatorics.org/) & [*Image Processing Online*](http://www.ipol.im/) (IPOL Journal) which both look like reputable, high-quality, publication-fee-free, algorithm-relevant journals to me.

Some of the information is a little out of date though, for instance the journal [*Algorithms*](http://www.mdpi.com/journal/algorithms) (MDPI) I think now charges [300 CHF (Swiss Francs)](http://www.mdpi.com/journal/algorithms/apc) although initially it was free, in the past.

Comment: Many MDPI journals were no-fee for their first couple of years and have since begun charging - I think this is now standard practice for them.

Comment: It's standard practice for most new open access journals - it makes sense IMO: new journals by definition don't have a journal impact factor (you need at least 2 years of citation data), so to some authors it is more of a 'risk' to publish there, so they need to do something to entice authors in the first couple of years before they get an impact factor.

Comment: As far as I can tell, MDPI _Algorithms_ is a write-only journal.

Comment: Harsh. Google Scholar seems to think differently: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Delaunay%20Meshing%20of%20Piecewise%20Smooth%20Complexes%20without%20Expensive%20Predicates (although, perhaps all the 29 citations didn't read the paper?) ;)

Comment: Thanks the DOAJ link helped me and I found a free journal for my paper.